# VScode configuration causes code to not execute

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am returning to learning C and was trying to get a basic code to print something to run, and for some reason, after debugging, and writing in the terminal `./{filename}.exe`, I get no output at all, and a message in the terminal that says `bash: ./test.exe: No such file or directory`. attached below is the configuration of the `launch.json`

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/c_projects.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You wrote the error message says `test.exe` while your configuration says `c_projects.exe`. Is that correct or were you just changing the executable's name for the question? The execuable may be found in `build/`. In the terminal you can use `ls` to find the file if it is just a naming problem.

Comment: @PeterKrebs these are different files... the c_projects.exe ran without any error, but when i created a new file which i wanted to run, and is the test.c, it didnt run at all... should i simply open a complete different project for this?

Comment: The error `No such file or directory` is certainly not lying - it couldn't find the file. Have you made sure it was compiled before? No uppercase/lowercase naming problems? It should be a simple problem, just having the executable in the correct place.

Comment: @PeterKrebs so it seems that after changing the last argument in tasks.json to the file i wish to compile, which is test.c, after compiling, the required output is given. what should i put in args so that i dont need to change the last argument for every specific file, as long as it is under the same project?

Comment: I haven't done that myself. Look at the available [VS Code variables for launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference). So maybe you want `${fileBasename}.exe`? You have to switch to the file with the `main()` before starting the debug session I suspect.